# Using EA as a registry

Tags: enterprise-architect

Besides using EA for developing and maintaining various model definitions - is it possible to use it as a repository of instance data?

Let's say that I have defined an class, "Activity". Can I use EA as a repo for the instances of this class?

In my particular use case I'm trying to document various aspects of our helpdesk. In addition to documenting the components pertaining to our support process, I would also like to store the actual implementation information pertaining to these components.

An example:

[image]

In a sense, I would like to use EA as a central database of configuration data (the collection of defined activities) and at the same time be able to trace each configuration data item to the formal class definition. Having the possibility to trace these relationships would make it easy for us to know what defined activities nned to be updated if we change the class model, and vice versa.

How can I implement this in EA?

Does this make sense, or am I completely off when it comes to what EA can be used for?

Comment: As a quick tip (someone might expand): use objects and runstate variables.

Comment: However, remember that anyone (!) can fumble around with what is in the repository. It's not better than any public Excel table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you could do that by creating instances of your classes and setting the run-state.

Create an instance by (Ctrl+) dragging your class onto a class diagram and choosing **Instance(Object)** for **Drop As:**

[image]

Then use the context menu option **Features | Set Run State (Ctrl + Shift + R)** to set the run states.

[image]

Whether or not this is a good idea I'll leave in the middle.